# Canon DSLR USB Chargers?

Tags: canon, battery, charger, power-supply, power

I'm wondering if there are any USB chargers available for canon DSLRs. I often head out for extended periods of time without electricity with my camera gear which always makes me nervous about when its going to run out. I've got something like this [(a campfire charging stove)](http://www.thepowerpot.com/power-pot-x?ref=cat_img) which produces at max about 10W of power. I'm wondering if there are any options for charging via USB? I'm using a 5D mkII/III.

If there aren't any USB based chargers around, what alternatives are there?

Thanks,

Comment: I didn't know such camping accessories existed, that's pretty amazing

Comment: @Dreamager Yeah, they're great. I also use a Biolite stove see: http://www.biolitestove.com/ for my Phone/iPod (that way i don't ever run out of fuel). If you're into EE/physics, its very interesting how they work...

Comment: The native battery for the EOS 5D Mk III seems to be the LP-E6, which at 7.2V 1800mAh provides about 13 Wh of juice. USB 1.x and 2.0 provides for up to 500mA at 5V (2.5W), so it'd take about 5 hours to fully charge such a battery from empty if the charging process is 100% efficient (which it isn't, particularly since you'd need to step up the voltage). Looking at those numbers, it'd seem *reasonable* that such a charger *exists*; however, I don't think I've ever seen one. One almost certainly could be built.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yeah, I haven't seen one as far as i can remember, i could design one i guess but i don't have the time at the moment...

Comment: Related: [Are there any DSLRs which can charge the battery via USB?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53237/are-there-any-dslrs-which-can-charge-the-battery-via-usb)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Bower XC-CE6 3-in-1 Individual Battery Charger for Canon LP-E6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057R2ZJA) description at amazon.com says it can charge your LP-E6 batteries via USB. I've never used one.

Comment: That looks like what I'm after. I'll have to see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @NULLZ Did you try this charger out? Could you maybe report back (in a comment) if this little experiment was successful? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NULLZ bump on that one too - would love to hear if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can find is using Solar panels that can output 12VDC and using a cigarette lighter car charger.  5V seems insufficient from what some quick research showed.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a 2-battery USB charger for $11 with 4.5 star review from > 500 reviewers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QGJ91A4). Finally, can travel without bulky AC adapter.