# Is there really no way to power a DSLR by USB?

Tags: dslr, battery, usb, power-supply, battery-drain

I made some scripts on my Raspberry Pi to automate a daily shot at a specific hour.

My DSLR is plugged in through USB. **I thought this would keep its battery charged, but no.**

Is there really no way automate a DSLR to shoot every 24 hours without having to pick it up, charge/replace its battery, and put in back on the same spot?

Comment: Maybe new DSLRs will be powered by USB. Now some mirrorless  cameras can be powered by USB, for example Sony a6300/a6500. But you still have to keep the camera battery inside the camera.

Comment: v3.2 USB-C has 100w and up to 20v.  More than enough for charging, if you can find a camera with this kind of port.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there really no way automate a DSLR to shoot every 24 hours without having to pick it up, charge/replace its battery, and put in back on the same spot ?

Canon and Nikon cameras can be connected to AC power by means of an adapter that fits in the battery slot. For example, Canon DSLRs that take an LB-E6 battery (like the 5D II, 6D, and 7D) can use an [ACK-E6 adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007FMG6D6):

[image: ACK-E6]

And Nikons that take a EN-EL14 battery (like D3200, D5200, etc.) can use this [EP-5A AC Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZYF3MS):

[image: EP-5A]

I've seen similar arrangements for other brands as well. The best plan is to check the list of accessories available for your camera -- there are sure to be solutions for powering your camera both from AC power and also from a 12V vehicle battery.

Comment: There are also cheap equivalents from companies like Hama. I've made my own for an old 350D based on a suitable power supply.

Comment: The same is true for Pentax DSLR's. Point of caution for cheap equivalents: I found it difficult to find an alternative adapter that has the right pin *and* the right voltage *and* that delivers the right power (ampere or watt) according to specifications. After some failed "cheaper" attempts, I ended up with the "official" adapter, which works fine.

Comment: @agtoever it took me a few tries with a bench supply and decent multimeter to build mine successfully.

Answer (score 6):

No, cameras can not be powered by a USB port because they typically require more than The 5 volts maximun available from the USB port.

Comment: It would be easy enough for the camera to include some sort of converter, to change the 5V to whatever it needs. It probably has a converter for the voltage from the batteries anyway.

Comment: It's not just volts - it is amps as well. When you step up the voltage you reduce the amps.

Comment: Which is to say, it's about *power*.

Comment: A USB-2.0 port can deliver up to 5W according to specification (5V, 1A) which is enough to drive a harddisk or a dvd-burner.  Things get much simpler if the host does not have to power the device - you may for instance talk to the camera using your low powered smartphone over USB.

Comment: In my tests, a 350D draws 1.5A at 8V for a brief moment after shooting with the flash.  So you'd need significant energy storage for a USB-powered system. (The ammeter reads at 4Hz, exactly one reading per shot was >1A, and I had 1500µF in the battery casing I had modified) (@vclaw et al.)  You could of course *charge a battery* using a voltage converter as many compacts do.  Maybe there's a battery grip with charge input.

Comment: Let's hope USB-C will change this - USB-C can provide up to 100W if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: There are plenty of USB power supplies that can provide 2.4A / 12W. So that should be enough for most cameras (except maybe for the flash). Though this is for USB power only, maybe a bit more complicated if you want to use USB for data as well.

Comment: Well, in this case he wants to take a single shot *once* per day, so that's a whole lot of time to charge for that single flash.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to do this over USB is unlikely but not impossible.

My Nikon D750 has `7-9V 2.5A` stamped on the bottom of it. That's a draw between 18W and 22W.

This is significant because you can buy USB step-up converters to get to 9V. The problem is most of these ([one example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5W-USB-DC-DC-5V-to-9V-Step-Up-Boost-Module-Moter-toy-car-boat-Security-Monitor-/281082163568)) are limited in terms of current output to around ~5W... And 7W before they start to melt.

I'm certain you'd start to get supply issues at the USB end too past a point.

So short of chaining together multiple supplies, this probably isn't going to be an option for a full-on DSLR. It *might* be an option for a lower-power camera especially if you can disable the screen, etc.

---

If you can do the timing internally (many DSLRs can) is a battery grip available? I'm not sure how many shots you're planning but in my experience the timer doesn't use that much power. I get weeks of standaby from mine. I could double that with a battery grip. Perhaps more with higher density batteries.

What's killing it for you is being hooked into a USB interface. Assuming you have good standby power usage, an external timer would be a better idea than leaving it on USB indefinitely.

---

A separate power supply is by far the better option but if you're out of range of an AC supply, a car battery can *easily* supply currents like 2.5A through a cheap step-down transformer. [This one can pump out 8A](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00GXXQ1VA). 12A if you improve the heatsink.

More than enough to power the camera. Add a 5V supply power supply and you can power the Raspi too.

The great thing about picking a 12V lead-acid supply setup is it's used everywhere and rural demands mean there are solutions for keeping batteries trickle-charged via solar (or mini wind/water turbines, etc). Indefinitely.

The problem now becomes keeping your camera protected. I'm not an electrical engineer (I'm just enthusiastic and well-caffeinated) so it might be ill-advised to stick something like that into your camera without additional smoothing and/or additional voltage regulation.

If you're uncomfortable with this sort of stuff, I'd aim to find a local electrical engineer. The parts cost for something like this (past the battery) really are negligible.

Comment: That *7-9V 2.5A* is probably peak power. If it were continuous the camera would get Real Hot and drain the batteries in no time. If the peak is very short (less than 100ms for instance) USB3 may suffice if you provide a large capacitor. It will take the USB power source a bit longer to charge the capacitor again, so you probably can't shoot faster than, say, 1 picture per couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get the voltage you need from USB is to use a cheap buck up/down (depending on whether you need more or less than 5V) convertor (such as the down convertor based on the MP1584, available for around a pound / dollar / euro) These can be around 80%+ efficient and shift the voltage from the 5V available on the USB port to whatever (within reason) you need. 
That solves the voltage problem, but what about the current ?
Most cameras only need a high current momentarily (when recharging the flash for instance) 
This can be achieved by adding a capacitor in parallel with the output of the convertor to provide a short duration of extra current.    Bear in mind that you may have to add a resistor between the capacitor and convertor to limit the current so as not to overload the output of the convertor when you switch on. (some convertors are safe and don't need this)

Answer (score 0):

Many DSLRs have external power jack (it is often cylindrical, like those which are used in laptops). Some others might use an AC adapter which fits into the battery compartment.

Most DSLRs cannot be powered through their USB port (in fact, I have not seen any that can).

Comment: None of the DSLRs that I have seen had a power jack. What let you arrive at the conclusion that *most* of them have one? Do you have a source?

Comment: @null: only one camera from those which my family owns does not have a power jack (and that is a DSLR, BTW). Still, corrected the post.

Comment: Since Nikon and Canon DSLRs don't have jacks for DC power, and Pentax DSLRs apparently don't either, what's the basis for your claim that "many" DSLRs have such a jack?

Comment: "Since Nikon and Canon DSLRs don't have jacks for DC power, and Pentax DSLRs apparently don't either": [1](http://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/images/pentax-k-3-ii-camrea-usb-3-cable-port-door-open.jpg), [2](http://www6.pcmag.com/media/images/217135-nikon-d300s-ports.jpg), [3](http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/producten/1350/testrapport/fujifilm_finepix_s9600_4B.jpg) (this one is not even a DSLR), [4](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/pentax-k1/ZPR-PENTAX-K1-LEFT-PORTS.JPG), [5](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/pentax-x5/ZPORTS.JPG)(not a dslr as well). Never was interested in Canon.

Comment: You see that that question is specific to DSLRs, right?

Comment: @caleb: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29089306#29089306

Answer (score 0):

I put together a homemade solution using an 8V 1A power supply and a capacitor in the old battery housings.  I'd recommend this approach *if* you're confident in your electronics ability, in particular in your ability to do it all patiently and carefully.  You could easily fry the camera if you get it wrong.  Access to a bench supply, combined with a camera that's on its last legs, are recommended.

Comment: This is more discussion than answer. Could you turn this into a true answer, without the discussion aspects?

Comment: @jrista I won't write a whole tutorial on a diy solution for an unknown camera I probably don't have access to. The only bit that's probably off-topic is the part about my trigger solution as the OP hasn't asked about the problem it solves. The rest is important to designing your own power adaptor.

Comment: Seems TFuto did an admirable job eliminating the discussion aspects. Seems good to me now...if you wish to add more useful answer details, feel free, but try to keep the "chattiness" down.

Comment: @jrista in more inclined to delete or at the moment. The useful point about power saving mode kicking in when running over USB is gone, and this is more likely with a homemade solution as I describe.

Comment: Add that point back in.

Answer (score 0):

There are no first-principle prohibitions to make a DSLR chargeable through the USB port. There are cameras with power consumption comparable to that of DSLRs, which support USB charging. Sony A7RII (introduced in 2015) can be charged from a power bank or PC while shooting. That is quite handy, I could record 4k videos non-stop for >1.5hours with a cable to a power bank in my pocket. Olympus OM-D E-M5III was the first Olympus model with a large DSLR-like sensor to support charging through its USB port. It has a micro-USB connector, same as Sony A7RII. Later models (OM-D E-M1III) with USB-C support tethered power supply to the camera. Technically these are not SLR (="single-lens reflex": no mirror/"reflex" part in these), yet the effect of the mirror on power consumption is insignificant.

If the question is specific about your particular DSLR -- well, if it does not provide an option to recharge the battery without removing it then unfortunately no way to solve your problem without seriously hacking the camera.

Answer (score 0):

While not a DSLR but a mirrorless camera, a Canon EOS R6 may be powered with a compatible USB-C power delivery adapter. The adapter just needs to support the correct voltage. If you buy the very expensive USB-C power delivery adapter from Canon, it does (the Canon adapter lists 5V/3A and 9V/3A). If you buy it from some other vendor, you have to ensure it's able to produce 5V and 9V both at 3A. Presumably the 9V is the voltage that the camera negotiates with the power delivery charger, and the 5V is there just for USB compatibility with devices that don't negotiate a voltage.