# Can I power a Canon EOS 1200D with mains power instead of battery?

Tags: canon, battery, power-supply

I have a Canon EOS 1200D, which uses LP-E10 batteries. I was wondering if anyone knows of a cable/adapter that can give the camera a continuous power supply from the wall, as I use it for live streaming a bit, and having it on battery for that when it is stationary is rather annoying.

How can I power the 1200D from mains (wall) power (not USB), rather than from batteries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there really no way to power a DSLR by USB?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76634/is-there-really-no-way-to-power-a-dslr-by-usb)

Comment: "Canon EOS 1200D power supply" as a web search?

Comment: @jdv See my answer, already found it.

Comment: Similar question on the Nikon side of the fence: [How can I run a Nikon D3100 from AC power?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76091/)

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of searching, I found the [DR-E10 DC Coupler](https://store.canon.co.uk/canon-dr-e10-dc-coupler/5112B001/) on the Canon website. Clearly when I was originally searching I was using the wrong key terms in my searches on google.

More searching then revealed that that adapter doesn't have the AC cord with it, so a better option would be the [Canon ACK-E10 Adaptor](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Canon-ACK-E10-Adaptor-EOS-1100D/dp/B004N867AC) (not on Canon UK store, so found on Amazon | Was listed on the Canon US site for the Rebel T5 aka the 1200D)

Comment: You can get cheap knock off versions of the ACK-E10 for about 1/4 the price of the Canon version, at least in the U.S. you can.

Comment: @MichaelClark I found one for about £15 on Amazon. Will report back once it arrives.